# Efficiently test if two lists have the same elements and length

Tags: python, list, function

I got 2 lists:

```
alist = ['A','B','C','D']
anotherList = ['A','C','B','D']
```

would like to write a function which returns `True` if both lists contain the exact same elements, and are same length. I'm kinda new on this stuff, so I got this, which I'm pretty sure it's terrible, and I'm trying to find a more efficient way. Thanks!

```
def smyFunction(aList,anotherList):
    n = 0
    for element in aList:
        if element in anotherList:
            n = n+1
    if n == len(aList):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the lists with [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) and then compare them with `==`:

```
>>> alist = ['A','B','C','D']
>>> anotherList = ['A','C','B','D']
>>> def smyFunction(aList,anotherList):
...     return sorted(aList) == sorted(anotherList)
...
>>> smyFunction(alist, anotherList)
True
>>>
```

You need to sort them first in case the elements are out of order:

```
>>> alist = ['A','B','C','D']
>>> anotherList = ['D','A','C','B']
>>> alist == anotherList
False
>>> sorted(alist) == sorted(anotherList)
True
>>>
```

---

Actually, it would probably be better to test the length of the lists first and then use `sorted`:

```
return len(alist) == len(anotherList) and sorted(alist) == sorted(anotherList)
```

That way, we can avoid the sorting operations if the lengths of the list are different to begin with (using `len` on a list has `O(1)` (constant) complexity, so it is very cheap).

Comment: Don't forget to test the length of the two lists first for a speed improvement when the two lists are of different sizes.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski - Good idea.  I'll implement it.

Answer (score 4):

The two ways that come to mind are:

1) Use `collections.Counter`

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(alist) == Counter(anotherList)
True
```

2) Compare the sorted lists

```
>>> sorted(alist) == sorted(anotherList)
True
```

Comment: The `Counter` solution is nice because it's linear O(n) rather than O(n log n).

Comment: @JohnKugelman - The `sorted` solution is *a lot* faster with smaller lists.  Running a simple `timeit` test yields `36.708395899478845` for `Counter` and just `3.7142343510138858` for `sorted`.  I would only recommend using `Counter` for large lists.

Comment: @iCodez in case there aren't duplicates, would it be faster to use, return set(alist) == set(anotherList) ?

Comment: @DWeiss23 - Yes, that is the fastest solution with a time of `2.1685054944136937`.  Of course, you should not just take my word for it but run your own tests.  [`timeit.timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) is available in every standard build of Python.

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't duplicates, use a `set`, it doesn't have an order:

```
set(alist) == set(anotherList)
```

Comment: -0.  Set doesn't work because `set([1, 2, 2, 3]) == set([1, 1, 2, 3])`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: don't need to rush, please *read* my answer.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm still partial to using either `sorted` or `Counter` because it works whether or not there are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
def check(a,b):
    return sorted(a) == sorted(b)
```